# ons-pageを二重に配置したページからpushPageを行うと新しいページが2回追加されてしまう

Tags: onsen-ui

pushPageで呼び出されたhtml内に＜ons-page＞を二重に配置しています。

```html
<ons-page modifier="p2">
  <img src="img/top.png" />

  <ons-page modifier="p2_c1">
    <img src="img/image.png" />
  </ons-page>

  <span id="ipt13">移動</span>
</ons-page>
```

このページにある要素を1回タップするとpushPageでさらに新しいページに遷移するようにしたのですが、
ページ追加処理が連続して2回実行されてしまいました。

なお＜ons-page＞の二重をやめて1つだけにしたところ、ページ移行は問題なく行われました。
このように二重で使用すると問題がありますでしょうか。

＜ons-page＞を二重にした理由は、ページ内の一部要素のみスクロール可能にしたいためです。
上記ソースの modifier="p2" の部分はCSSでスクロール禁止にし、modifier="p2_c1" の部分を
スクロール許可にしています。

Answer (score 1):

OnsenUIでは`ons-page`のネストはおそらく想定されていないと思います。ページ内の一部要素をスクロール可能にしたい場合は、当該部分に`ons-page`ではなく`ons-scroller`を使用します。
http://ja.onsen.io/reference/ons-scroller.html